# SvelteKit: slug-parameters get mixed up with media-path

Tags: svelte, server-side-rendering, sveltekit, slug, dynamic-routing

I work on a project, where I want to implement dynamic routing. I use multiple slug-parameters like number of article and author.
Example: blog.com/posts/**johnson/12**

On the 'posts'-page I get the parameters with:

```
import { page } from '$app/stores';
let author = $page.params.author;
let articleID = $page.params.articleID;
```

I also have a component on the 'posts'-page that contains an icon.svg in the static/img folder, which causes the following problem: **when I console.log the parameters I get author=johnson and articleID=12 on the client-console and author=img and articleID=icon.svg on the server.**

Because of that, I am unable to show the correct blog post. I searched through all of the official SvelteKit-Docs and similar questions on the web, but I couldn't find anything.

When I remove the component containing the SVG it works just fine. I also tried to import the component after `import { page } from '$app/stores';` but this did not help. I don't really have an Idea what I could do besides that.

My guess would be, that it has something to do with the SSR of SvelteKit, but I am not sure.
I have some experience with Svelte, but I am new to SvelteKit and would be glad if you helped me! :)

Comment: I had the exact same problem, and though the debugging log is pure nonsense, I have vague memory it was my bad and it had to do with my server load not returning the right payload.

Comment: What do you mean by "on the server"? Which function, which file?

Comment: @H.B. I mean the console in VS Code. There I get the media-path as parameters and on the browser-console I get the correct parameters.  I have also tried to remove the component completely, but then the same happens with the font-file. Also there is an error to load the SVG, because it tries to load the media from blog.com/posts/johnson/12/img/icon.svg which does apparently not work.

Comment: The fact that an SVG is requested on the route should be the actual problem here. Show how you attempt to load the SVG. Are you missing the leading slash that makes the path absolute?

Comment: @H.B. thanks for the hint, the missing leading slash was indeed missing. (facepalm) Now it works as expected every time but the first time after loading the page. I should also add, that i changed the import now to `import { page } from '$app/stores';` and reference it in the function below with `$page.params.author`. But I have no idea why it does not work at the first time :/

Comment: The first load is server-side rendered, maybe something on that page is incompatible with that. You should try to isolate the issue by removing as much as possible and show all of the relevant code.

Comment: @H.B. Thank you a lot for you help, I could finally find the issue! The problem was a util-function I had not correctly adjusted for SvelteKit. Now everything works fine when the pages are switched by the app. The only Issue I noticed is, that if you try to call the URL with the params directly, it does not work. I still try to figure out where the differences between the svelte-spa-router and the SvelteKit-router are so i can fix this last issue. :)